# Access Service/Factory data in AngularJS Controller

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, scope, controllers

I am trying to access data for my gauge chart controller from a factory .But it is not accepting the data .I am just passing a static value from the factory to the controller for now(later need to call a service to get json data). Below are my code snippets.

```
    Factory:
    var demoService= angular.module('demoService',[])
    .factory(myFactory,function(){
    var factory={};
    var data=8000;
    factory.getCustomers= function() {
    return data;
    };
    return factory;
    })
```

This is how i am calling it in the controller.js :

```
    angular.module("app.controllers", [])
    .controller("gaugeCtrl", ["$scope","config","myFactory",
function ($scope,config,myFactory) {
    return $scope.gaugeHome = {
      gaugeData: {
        maxValue: 9000,
        animationSpeed: 100,
        val: myFactory.getCustomers();

      },
      gaugeOptions: {
        lines: 12,
        angle: 0,
        lineWidth: 0.47,
        pointer: {
          length: 0.6,
          strokeWidth: 0.03,
          color: "#555555"
        },
        limitMax: "false",
        colorStart: config.secondary_color,
        colorStop: config.secondary_color,
        strokeColor: "#F5F5F5",
        generateGradient: !0,
        percentColors: [
          [0, config.secondary_color],
          [1, config.secondary_color]
        ]
      }
    }
```

I have also included the service Module in my app.js :

```
   var app = angular.module("app",["demoService"])
```

But this gauge chart won't show the values as given in the service .Am i missing something , or do i need to add the service module somewhere else too ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `.factory(myFactory,function(){` the first parameter should be a string, you are passing in an object. Add quotes around it: `.factory("myFactory",function(){`. Also, you should not have a return statement in your controller, remove the `return`

Comment: I tried that , but it didn't work either .Do i need to change the data passed from the service.

Comment: Once check the your code.I found some wrongs then prepare the http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yes, it worked well after i removed the ";" from ` val: myFactory.getCustomers();` .Thanks